# Sleep between sftp put commands

Tags: batch-file, sftp, wait

Is there a way to execute `sftp` with the `-c` command and in the text file specify an equivalent of `sleep` command to wait between two `put` commands?

I have a batch file that will sftp and execute a few `put` commands. I want the process to wait for 5 min after executing a few `put` commands.

```
sftp -b commands.txt ..
```

and in `commands.txt` I want:

```
put abc.txt
wait 5 mins
put xyz.txt
```

Worst case I could split it in my batch file into two txt files, but was wondering if there was an easier way so I don't have an extra file to maintain. Went through the `sftp` man pages didn't find anything that does that.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the commands to the `sftp`. That allows you to use shell `sleep` command.

```
(
echo put abc.txt
sleep 5m
echo put xyz.txt
) | sftp -b - user@example.com
```

---

You can of course sleep between two individual `sftp` commands too. Particularly, with such a long pause as 5 minutes, chances that the connection breaks meanwhile are not negligible.

```
echo put abc.txt | sftp -b - user@example.com
sleep 5m
echo put xyz.txt | sftp -b - user@example.com
```

---

On Windows, replace the `sleep 5m`, with:

```
timeout /t 300 > nul
```